# get the follow posts based on date

Tags: php, mysql

In the following tables in mysql of users following/being subscribed to other users (related in th 'follow' table) I would like to get the posts posted by the users to which a given user is subscribed:

table 1: follow

```
|-----------------------------------------|
|   id      |    uid     |    friends     |
|-----------------------------------------|
|   1       |     1      |      2         |
|   2       |     1      |      3         |
|   3       |     2      |      1         |
|-----------------------------------------|
```

table 2: posts

```
|-----------------------------------------------------|
|   id  |  uid   |    posts    |  date                |
|-----------------------------------------------------|
|   1   |   1    |   hai..     |  2013-07-08 01:56:09 |
|   2   |   5    |   awesome   |  2013-07-08 11:45:50 |
|   3   |   2    |   greate!!  |  2013-07-09 21:13:29 |
|   4   |   3    |   himm..    |  2013-07-10 12:06:10 |
|   5   |   2    |   super..   |  2013-07-10 14:50:09 |
|-----------------------------------------------------|
```

table3: user

```
|---------------------------|
|   uid     |     name      |
|---------------------------|
|   1       |     ram       |
|   2       |     syed      |
|   3       |     seeta     |
|---------------------------|
```

For example:
Given the user with uid 1, who follows both users with uid 2 and 3, I would like to display **my posts** and the **latest posts of the followes**.

The result would look like this:

```
   2 posted   
   super..  
     time:2013-07-10 14:50:09

   3 posted   
   himm..  
     time:2013-07-10 12:06:10

   2 posted   
   greate!!  
     time:2013-07-09 21:13:29

   1 posted   
   hai..  
     time:2013-07-08 01:56:09
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: In which format are the tables given? Is it mysql?

Comment: @Sikian tables in mysql format only

Comment: @prasanth I've added a solution given it's in mysql :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure if your tables are in sql, but in case they are, I think the best way to get the data as you want is with a LEFT JOIN as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM follow
JOIN posts
ON (follow.friends = posts.uid OR follow.uid = posts.uid)
WHERE follow.uid = {user_uid}
```

Where {user_id} is the user id you want.

If this is the case, please take a further look to joins (f.e. at [tizag](http://www.tizag.com/sqlTutorial/sqljoin.php)) and left joins.

Comment: @prasanth No problem, I'm glad I could help. Btw, try to make questions clearer next time ;)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your user id is 5:

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE posts.uid IN (SELECT follow.friends FROM follow WHERE follow.uid=5)
```

Or you can join the tables:

```
SELECT posts.* FROM posts JOIN follow ON posts.uid = follow.friends WHERE follow.uid=5
```

If you want to see your own posts as well:

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE posts.uid=5 OR posts.uid IN (SELECT follow.friends FROM follow WHERE follow.uid=5)
```

Comment: I just realized posts by the same user where wanted as well, maybe you'd like to update your answer :)

Comment: @Jesbus your query is correct..but i getting only the post of follower.i need follower post along with my post (uid) also..

Comment: Sorry, I will update my answer.